# NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined error using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nameerror

Am receiving this error that WebDriver is not defined and not sure what is causing it.

Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# Opening the connection and grabbing the page
my_url = 'https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en'
option = Options()
option.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(my_url)
driver.maximize_window()
```

And the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-36e4c75bf698> in <module>
     10 option = Options()
     11 option.headless = False
---> 12 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
     13 driver.get(my_url)
     14 driver.maximize_window()

NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined
```

Am running it on Jupyter notebooks.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Where is your `chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: You never imported webdriver. Add the line `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: @Jortega in C:, locaation: \anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.6-h60c2a47_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined
```

...implies that *`NameError`* was raised while executing the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

as you haven't imported the *`webdriver`* module.:

---

### Solution

Apart from importing the other modules you also have to include the webdriver module as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```